# Why does the pound sign fails to display correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a page that has pound signs "£" both visible and within select options (emitted by asp:DropDownLists).  This page displays the pound sign correctly on my local version however when it's in the live environment it displays it as "Â£".  Ah you're saying, you've got encoding set differently between the two environments, but I don't as both versions of IIS are showing the same!  Pound signs appear correctly on other pages within the application in the live environment and according to WinMerge there's no difference between either the .aspx or code behind pages.

So a bit of a hair pulling problem at the moment (although hopefully someone will point out something really obvious!).  So the question is...why isn't it displaying correctly on this one page in the live environment?

Comment: What are the HTTP headers, and what is the source file encoding on the server?

Comment: I just checked and Â£ is definitely the win1252 and iso-8859-1 representation of the UTF-8 bytes for £. So somewhere utf-8 code is being read as win1252 or iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the string format like this  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/format-a-

```
   decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m;
    string html = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue);
    Console.WriteLine(html);
or
    decimal value = 123.45M;
        CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        string s = string.Format(us, "{0:C}", value);
```

Comment: Hi melnajjar that displays correctly however it doesn't explain why the page is displaying incorrectly.

Comment: @Norman can you see what localize english you are using in your server.  if you are dve machine in english UK it must be the same in your server

Answer (score 0):

Could you work around the issue by using

```
&pound;
```

instead, the HTML equivalent?

Comment: I think I'm going to have to.  Sadly it's legacy code so I was more interested in why it was happening rather then having to go through a do the replacement.  But I think I will.